# Остановить выполнение setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

```
$(setInterval (function() { 
    if ( $("#online_counter").html() == 1) {
        $("wrapper").hide();
    }
    if ( $("#online_counter").html() == 2) {
        window.location.replace(document.location.href);
        $("wrapper").show();
    }
}, 3000 ));
```

Уважаемые, а можно ли с помощью jQuery остановить выполнение *setInterval*, когда выполнится условие 2?

Comment: Можно. Но только без jQuery ибо в jQuery нет таймеров.

Comment: `var timer = setInterval(...);  clearInterval(timer);` а зачем, Вы же все равно перегружаете страницу?

Comment: @Igor, это же не jQuery! :)

Comment: @DmitriySimushev А я-то уже собирался это в качестве ответа использовать. Спасибо, что предупредили!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тело второго условия (`if ( $("#online_counter").html() == 2) {` это же?) перезагружает страницу, что уже говорит о плохом коде и подходе. Назначьте переменной ID интервала и очищайте по нему:

```
$(function() {
  let id = setInterval(function() { // setInterval возвращает уникальный ID вида: 3681
    if ($("#online_counter").html() == 1) {
      $("wrapper").hide();
    }
    if ($("#online_counter").html() == 2) {
      clearInterval(id); // Функция уничтожения интервала по ID
      $("wrapper").show();
    }
  }, 3000)
});
```

Comment: А вы господин предельно хороши.

Comment: таймер будет нагревать страницу нехило, так предупреждение, на телефоне высадит батарею если не вырубить

Comment: @BimBam, я смущён :)

Comment: @SergeEsmanovich, как и любой код, интервал просто регулярно запускается. Но тут раз в 3 секунды и простенькая проверка - не самое страшное, что может быть. Но, конечно, очищать необходимо, а лучше вообще избегать этого (интервалы коварны), подобную проблему можно было бы решить с помощью `DOM MutationObserver`.